# Retrieve comma separated foreign key table data using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a column which saves user id's as comma separated values

```
'32,12,64'
```

What is best way of getting the related table data using Entity Framework if possible as `[NotMapped]` property in partial class of `Task`, since there is a trigger to maintain audit history moving user id's to child table is not possible. Please see sample code below

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string UserIds { get;set; }
    public string UserNames { get;set; }
}

var task = GetCurrentTask()

foreach(var userId in task.UserIds.Split(','))
{
   task.UserNames += GetUserNameFor(userId);
}
```

Comment: do you want username as comma separated value?

Comment: Yes.User name as comma separated.

Comment: Currently we use trigger to capture history details of table so when a child table is used we cannot capture audit history of child table.

Comment: strictly speaking, comma separated values are no FK's in any way, since you have no guaranteeing the targeted property will be a key, the index on this property is missing (+impossible to maintain) and the inclusion constraint (FK constraint) is not in place. If you want to go with it (I strongly suggest to follow @marc_s's advice and alter your schema), you can split, parse and use the .Contains (IN in SQL) method; but I can already tell this is going to break quite soon.

Comment: But how can I capture history of table row edit history in that case

Comment: Since you need many FK's, this sounds like a job for a many-to-many relationship with mapping table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, UserIDs field is String so, you can query using LINQ if you have the value of this field.

```
var userIDs = "32,12,64";
var result = Usertable.retrieve(x=> x.UserID.Contains(userIDs)).ToList();
```

Try this way. You can find all the data from the User table with all fields value in results.

Comment: Is it possible to use this as [NotMapped] property in Task table partial class

Comment: I have not tried with [NotMapped] property yet. So, I am not very sure about it, please try once if it workes for you.